# Why my tooltip can't overflow outside of its parent element?

Tags: html, css, tooltip

Sorry for the ugly HTML/CSS but I used a tool called SnappySnippet to capture the HTML/CSS of a part of my own website.

You can see my problem here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wjgcm

I have a `Favorite` element where a tooltip should normally be shawn at the bottom.

This `Favorite` as position relative, and the tooltip has position `absolute` to be placed just at the bottom of the Favorite element. The tooltip has the place I want it to have but unfortunately I don't really know why the tooltip it cut because it can't overflow one of it's parent div.

Can someone tell me what is wrong? The div that should overflow is actually the div with id `DIV_22`

Comment: You've answered your question: *because it can't overflow one of it's parent div.*

Comment: I know the cause but I don't know how to fix this :)

Comment: Don't know it fit your needs but try removing all `overflow` declarations, including `auto` or `hidden`.

Comment: You have set `overflow: hidden` for lots of id's, for clearfix purposes perhaps? I guess you can just set all `overflow`s to `visible` and try to use a different clearfix approach like on this reference: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: Hashem it seems to work but actually I do not want these elements to overflow, I just want the tooltip to be able to overflow! :) How can I keep this elements not overflowing and having the tooltip overflowing instead